# Delete partition - Partition number

Tags: partition, hard-disk

I want to delete the partition /dev/sdb5 from my hard disk and then distribute the resulting space to other partitions. Now what would be the consequences in doing so? Would the partition numbers greater than 5 be renumbered? E.g. would /dev/sdb7 become /dev/sdb6 upon deletion? This would create problems for fstab entries.

[image: partition table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the kernel will show your partitions with different numbers.

You should change your `fstab` to rely on [UUID](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab#UUIDs) (or labels) – it is more robust anyway. Use `blkid` to find your partitions UUIDs.

On a side note: I see `sdb6` is located after `sdb7`. The number is derived from the order of the partitions as defined in the partition table, not their position on the disk. Tools like `fdisk` or `gdisk` allow sorting the partition definition order by partition position.